# Formatar ano no SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Preciso formatar um *timestamp* no seguinte formato:

```
DDMMYYHHMMSS
```

Consegui usando o *strftime*, exemplo:

```
select strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M%S", current_timestamp) from stream;
```

Mas essa forma ele mostra 4 digitos para o ano e preciso somente dos dois últimos, como formatar já que `%y` não é válido.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez a melhor solução seja tratar isto direto na linguagem de programação, visto que o *strftime()* no **SQLite** não implementa todas as opções de formatação do *strftime()* da linguagem **C**. Mas se você não puder fazê-lo a solução é executar a função duas vezes, cortar e concatenar:

```
select strftime('%d%m', current_timestamp)||substr(strftime("%Y%H%M%S", current_timestamp),3);
300318195604
```

Mas o resultado final é meio confuso.

Answer (score 0):

A sugestão da resposta de [Giovanni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/50856/giovanni-nunes) é interessante, não lhe serve?

Não conheço uma forma *"direta"* de trazer o ano com apenas dois caracteres (ex `yy` ou `%y`), então minha sugestão seria contornar isso e retornar uma *[substring](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/substr.php)* da sua consulta. (considerando que obrigatoriamente você precisa retornar do *bd* com a data neste formato, ao invés de tratar isso via linguagem):

```
select substr(strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M%S", current_timestamp), 3) from stream;
```